# "Defragmenting" a list

Tags: code-golf

A fragmented file is a file which is seperated into several parts on a harddrive, because it can't fit into a certain space.

On all harddrives, there are files called unmovable files, which are unmovable. To simulate real data on a harddrive, the input will also have unmovable files.

You are given several sequences of consecutive numbers, all scrambled into one list. The goal is to order each of these sequences so that they are placed in as little space as possible. *The list can be as big as you need it to be.* If there is no space for a sequence, then put a `-` instead.

To mark the unmovable files, another list, with the same length as the data, will be given after you recieve the data. It will contain either a 0 or a 1. Every 1 within that list means that the corresponding item in the data is unmovable.

Shortest code wins.

**Test Cases**

The output does not have to be exactly like this, but the length needs to be the same, and all of the sequences need to be ordered.

```
[ 0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]
[25, 30, 11, 12, 13, 14, 68, 69, 31, 26, 32]
Output: [25, 26, 11, 12, 13, 14, 68, 69, 30, 31, 32]
(output length: 11)

[0, 0, 0,  0, 0,  1,  1,  1, 0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0]
[2, 3, 5, 14, 8, 10, 11, 12, 4, 6, 28, 30, 29, 15, 16, 7]
Output: [14, 15, 16, -, -, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 28, 29, 30]
(output length: 18)
```

Comment: If some part of the challenge is not explained well, tell me! I cannot explain things well.

Comment: Yes, the rule telling how we are supposed to eliminate some sequence is not clear (why the 8 instead of the 2 in last example). Also the fact that 15 is present twice in the last array is confusing me...

Comment: @Orabîg: ! The last example has a lot of mistakes. I'll fix that.

Comment: In the 2nd example, the output length still isn't equal to the input length? Am I misunderstanding? Is the hard drive growing?

Comment: @marinus: Every small list must be fit into the big one, so it can increase in size. (you can think of it as a hard drive with infinite space, but the space alloted for the files grows)

Comment: @beary605: You might want to put that in your question. It's not obvious.

Comment: @beary605: Fixed my program to comply.

Comment: What is the correct output, given the input [0 1 0 0 0][1 3 8 2 9]?

Comment: @r.e.s.: [- 3 1 2 8 9] or [- 3 8 9 1 2]

Comment: I tried to clarify your question by illustrating the fitting with a better alignment, and only then I realized, which rule applies to `unmoveable data`. It means, you may write your own data to this places where there is a 1, but it must not overlap? What has it to do with `unmoveable`?

Comment: @userunknown: It's probably yet another error with my examples. Unmovable data cannot be touched. Unless you're referring to the one above, which is `- 3 1 2 8 9`, not `-3 1 2 8 9`.

Comment: I'm referring to example 1: 11-14 is mapped to the 4 places, occupied by ones, isn't it?

Comment: @userunknown: Yes it is. I don't see the problem, it's still in the same place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### APL (<s>132</s> <s>126</s> <s>123</s> <s>147</s> <s>145</s> 143)

This was a bit harder than I thought it'd be :)

Edit: the hard drive is infinite :S. All sequences that could not fit in the original space, are now appended onto the end of the output.

```
F←⍬⋄{×⍴⍵:∇1↓⍵⊣{∨/P←S⍷⍨1⍴⍨⍴⍵:S[R]∘←0⊣D[R←1-⍨(⍳⍴⍵)+⌊/P/⍳⍴P]∘←⍵⋄F∘←F,⍵}⊃⍵⋄D[S/⍳⍴S]∘←'-'}G[⍒⊃∘⍴¨G←K⊂⍨1≠|-⌿K,[÷2]¯1⌽K←K[⍋K←(S←~⎕)/D←⎕]]⋄F,⍨D/⍨~⌽∧\⌽S
```

This is what it does to your 1st and 2nd example <s>(the 2nd example is different, but in your example the output length is not the same as the input length and you said in a comment it was wrong, so...)</s>

```
⎕:    25 30 11 12 13 14 68 69 31 26 32
⎕:    0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0 
25 26 11 12 13 14 30 31 32 68 69
```

```
⎕:    2 3 5 14 8 10 11 12 4 6 28 30 29 15 16 7
⎕:    0 0 0 0  0 1  1  1  0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0
14 15 16 - - 10 11 12 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 28 29 30
```

Explanation:

- `F←⍬`: set `F` to the empty list. This will hold the overflow.
- `K←K[⍋K←(S←~⎕)/D←⎕]`: read two lists. The first list (numbers) is stored in `D`. The second list (whether the data is unmovable) is *inverted* and then stored in `S`. Get all movable numbers, and sort them. Store this in `K`.
- `G←K⊂⍨1≠|-⌿K,[÷2]¯1⌽K`: Subtract each element of `K` from the next element of `K`. Wherever this is not 1, we found the beginning of a new sequence. Store the list of sequences in `G`.
- `G[⍒⊃∘⍴¨G`...`]`: sort the list of sequences by descending length. This way, we place the longest sequences first.
- `{×⍴⍵:...}G`: as long as this list of sequences is not empty...
- `∇1↓⍵⊣`: handle the tail of the list, after...
- `{...}⊃⍵`: doing the following with the head:
- `∨/P←S⍷⍨1⍴⍨⍴⍵`: find, in `S`, a list of ones that is as long as the current sequence (`⍵`).
- `S[R]∘←0⊣D[R←1-⍨(⍳⍴⍵)+⌊/P/⍳⍴P]∘←⍵`: if there is one, store `⍵` in `D` at the first position that it fits, and mark these positions as unmovable in `S`.
- `⋄F∘←F,⍵`: if there is no room, add it to the overflow.
- `⋄D[S/⍳⍴S]∘←'-'`: when we're at the end of the list of sequences, all positions where `S` is still one are places where we couldn't put anything. Mark these with `-`.
- `⋄F,⍨D/⍨~⌽∧\⌽S`: then, at the end, display D, with the trailing `-`s removed, followed by the overflow (`F`) per the new rules.

Comment: wow, it was still wrong. :( Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @marinus Above you say you place the longest sequence first. If so is this optimum. What would your code do with:[0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0][5 2 3 14 1 17 9 10 11 12 18 16 15 7 6]

Answer (score 0):

I decided to tackle this solution in Scala, taking advantage of both functional and imperative features of the hybrid language. Here is the code for my solution.

```
def orderedSequences(filePieces: List[(Int,Int)]): List[List[(Int,Int)]] = {
  def orderedSequencesR(filePieces: List[(Int,Int)], currentSequence: List[(Int,Int)], sequences: List[List[(Int,Int)]]): List[List[(Int,Int)]] = {
    if(filePieces == Nil) sequences :+ currentSequence
    else if(currentSequence == List.empty) orderedSequencesR(filePieces.tail, List(filePieces.head), sequences)
    else if(filePieces.head._2 == currentSequence.last._2 + 1) orderedSequencesR(filePieces.tail, currentSequence :+ filePieces.head, sequences)
    else orderedSequencesR(filePieces, List.empty, sequences :+ currentSequence)
  }
  orderedSequencesR(filePieces, List.empty, List.empty)
}

def defragment(sequences: List[List[(Int,Int)]], filePieces: List[(Int,Int)]): List[Any] = {
  val largestSequenceLength = sequences.flatten.length
  var solution = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[(Int,Int)]()

  filePieces foreach {filePiece => if(filePiece._1 == 1) solution += filePiece  else solution += ((-1,0))}

  solution ++ Iterator.fill(largestSequenceLength)((-1,0))

  sequences foreach {
      sequence =>
      var sequenceIsInserted = false
      var currentPosition = 0
      while(!sequenceIsInserted) {
        if(solution.slice(currentPosition,currentPosition + sequence.length).forall((s: (Int,Int)) => s._1 == -1)){
          solution = solution.slice(0,currentPosition) ++ sequence ++ solution.slice(currentPosition + sequence.length, solution.length)
          sequenceIsInserted = true
        }
        currentPosition += 1
      }
  }

  solution.map(_._2).toList
}

def getDefragmentedFiles(isUnmovable: List[Int], files: List[Int]) = {
    val filePieces = isUnmovable zip files
    val sequences = orderedSequences(filePieces.filter(os => os._1 == 0).sortBy(t => t._2))
    val bestSolution = defragment(sequences.permutations.toList.sortBy {b => defragment(b, filePieces).length}.head, filePieces)
    println(bestSolution map { case 0 => '-'; case x => x })  
}

val isUnmovable = List(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
val files = List(2,3,5,14,8,10,11,12,4,6,28,30,29,15,16,7)
getDefragmentedFiles(isUnmovable, files)
```

I take the list of movable/unmovable positions along with the files and zip them up. I then get the movable files, sort them in order, and pass them into orderedSequences to get a list of file sequences.

Once I get the sequences, I get all the permutations of the sequences and I brute-force defrag them, taking the solution of the shortest length. This is pretty inefficient, but I can't think of a more efficient solution right now. The defrag method takes each sequence, in order, and iterates through the memory space until a valid spot to place the sequence is found.

After getting the best solution, I prettify it and print it out as a list.

Comment: An uncryptified answer is fine, but the question is tagged 'code golf', so you should produce a radically shortened version of the answer, and count its characters.